# Android instrumentation test failed due to mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, android-instrumentation, koin

Hi i am getting the following error

```
org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create definition for 'Single [name='NetworkControllerContract',class='com.network.contract.NetworkControllerContract']' due to error :

Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.network.NetworkController.
```

I have manually made those classes open..

```
open class NetworkController constructor(private val networkHelper: NetworkHelperContract) : NetworkControllerContract{.....}

open interface NetworkControllerContract {
}

//my test class

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyUnitTest: KoinTest {

   single<NetworkControllerContract> {
            Mockito.mock(NetworkController::class.java) //where it crashes
        }

   val networkController: NetworkControllerContract by inject()

}
```

Dependencies i use

```
   def mockito = "2.21.0"

//android instrumental test
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
    }
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.github.tmurakami:dexopener:2.0.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:0.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing:0.6.0'

    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito"
    androidTestImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito") {
        exclude group: 'org.mockito'
    }

    androidTestImplementation('org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.mockito'
    }

 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito"
    testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing-ktx:0.6.0'
    testImplementation 'com.jraska.livedata:testing:0.6.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is my decision for mocking

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class DashboardFragmentTest : KoinTest {
@Rule
@JvmField
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(SingleFragmentActivity::class.java, true, true)
@Rule
@JvmField
val executorRule = TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule()
@Rule
@JvmField
val countingAppExecutors = CountingAppExecutorsRule()

private val testFragment = DashboardFragment()

private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
private lateinit var router: Router

private val devicesSuccess = MutableLiveData<List<Device>>()
private val devicesFailure = MutableLiveData<String>()

@Before
fun setUp() {
    dashboardViewModel = Mockito.mock(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(dashboardViewModel.devicesSuccess).thenReturn(devicesSuccess)
    Mockito.`when`(dashboardViewModel.devicesFailure).thenReturn(devicesFailure)
    Mockito.`when`(dashboardViewModel.getDevices()).thenAnswer { _ -> Any() }

    router = Mockito.mock(Router::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(router.loginActivity(activityRule.activity)).thenAnswer { _ -> Any() }

    StandAloneContext.loadKoinModules(hsApp + hsViewModel + api + listOf(module {
        single(override = true) { router }
        factory(override = true) { dashboardViewModel } bind ViewModel::class
    }))

    activityRule.activity.setFragment(testFragment)
    EspressoTestUtil.disableProgressBarAnimations(activityRule)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    activityRule.finishActivity()
    StandAloneContext.closeKoin()
}

@Test
fun devicesCall() {
    onView(withId(R.id.rv_devices)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isCompletelyDisplayed()))
    Mockito.verify(dashboardViewModel, Mockito.times(1)).getDevices()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your setup:

`testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito"`

This dependency uses Android internals, which aren't available when you run Unit tests.